# Retracing proguard whole logcat with time option

Tags: android, logcat, android-proguard

I have a logcat generated with the following command:

```
adb logcat -d -v time > logcat.log
```

Which results in an output formatted as follows:

```
01-22 09:03:53.482 D/com.mydomain.myapp.g.a.c( 5255): Some logcat message
```

Then I retrace with the following command :

```
.\retrace.bat -regex "(?:.*/)%c(?:.*)" .\mapping.txt .\test.log > .\test_retraced.log
```

However, the output remains the same as the original file. The manuel seems to refer only to stack trace outputs : https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/retrace

Is it possible to retrace whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a while with the regex option I came to a simple regex which covers my case (see format above) :

```
.\retrace.bat -regex "(?:.*/)%c(?:.*)" .\mapping.txt .\test.log > .\test_retraced.log
```

This regex will only retrace the class names used as tags. You can play around with the regex for you own logging convention. For some reason the "/" is important, if removed it did not match.

The output was such :

```
01-22 09:03:53.482 D/com.mydomain.myapp.package.package.Class( 5255): Some logcat message
```